# Linking.openURL("https://www.google.com/") infinite loop(tabs) ,how can i get single?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Linking.openURL("https://www.google.com/");
giving infinite loop. how can i get single tab ?

```
Linking.openURL("https://www.google.com/");
```

Comment: A single line of code isn't very useful. Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we've enough context to understand what your code is doing and see why it's looping?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read how to ask question here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Your code does not indicate why `Linking.openURL` would result in an infinite loop. Share other relevant code as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your Linking.openURL as that

```
            <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => Linking.openURL("https://www.google.com/")}>
           
          </TouchableOpacity>
```